# Database design ideas for "master and slave" nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, architecture, master-slave

We are currently in design phase of a product. The idea is that we have a master (calling it) which contains all user information including user/registration/role/licence etc. and we have a slave database (calling it) which contains main application related data.

Some columns from the master database will be used in the slave database. for e.g. userid will be used everywhere in the slave database. There will be multiple versions of salve in different tiers (depending on customers subscription). So for e.g. Some customer will have a dedicated slave databases for their application.

Also some data/tables/columns from slave will be used in master.

How do we manage this scenario so that we can have maximum referential integrity (I know it will not be possible all the time) without using linked servers. (We dont want to use linked servers because for improper design it can be abused and can effect performance as a result).

Or is this a bad idea. Just have single database design (no master/slave) with different nodes. And customer's data in different nodes depending on their subscription? The problem that I see with this is that the registration/user tables are now fragmented in different database nodes. So for e.g. userA will be in database01 and so on.

Any idea?

Comment: Are all these databases on different physical servers?

Comment: they can be on same or different servers. thx

Comment: Why do you need users info in one database?